# What´s the difference between "lay out" and "put" in this phrase?

Tags: single-word-requests, differences, what

I'm from Brazil and I'm learning English.
I recently came across a phrase that intrigued me a bit...

*"Brenda wants to have a picnic. She drives to the park. She **lays out** a blanket."*

Can I use "put" instead of "lays out"? If so, what is the difference between them, and if not, why?

Comment: _Put_ requires a location to be specified for the putting, as well as a direct object to put there. _Lay out_, on the other hand, requires an object, too, but presupposes the location from context, though it can be added: _She lays out a blanket there._

Comment: Are you aware of our sister site English Language Learners at https://ell.stackexchange.com/ ?  You may find that better suited to your needs as an English Learner.

Comment: The meaning aside, you can't replace *lays out* with just *put*; you'd have to replace *lays out* with *puts outs*. Assuming, that is, you didn't modify anything else in the sentence. (*She **put** a blanket* is ungrammatical.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To lay out is to spread something flat on a surface; to put merely means to place something. You could say 'she puts a blanket on the ground', but that does not convey the spreading flat meaning.